# Laravel - Eager Loading get only first result

Tags: laravel-4, eager-loading

I need to get all the user from my database excluding only the user that belongs to `Admin` and `Staff` group and I need, for each of them, to get their profile so I used the Eager Loading:

```
$data['users'] = User::with('profile')->join('role_user', function($join){
    $join->on('role_user.user_id', '=' , 'users.id');
})
->join('roles', function($join){
    $join->on('roles.id', '=', 'role_user.role_id');
})
->whereNotIn('roles.name', ['Admin', 'Staff'])
->withTrashed()
->paginate(10);
```

My DB Table:

```
users:  
id | email | password

profile:
user_id | first_name | last_name

roles:
id | name

role_user:
user_id | role_id |
```

The problem is that the code above works with `user` infos but shows only the first `profile` so I have the same `first_name and last_name` with different `email`

Comment: You are selecting multiple `id` fields from all the tables, so `id` on your models gets overriden. Use relationship, will be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this should work:

```
   $users = \User::with('profile', 'roles')
->whereRaw('roles.name', '!=' 'Admin', 'OR', 'roles.name', '!=', 'Staff')
->withTrashed()->paginate(10);
```